# How to define the scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have:

**price_plan.rb**

```
class PricePlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  scope :premium, lambda { where('price > ?', 0) }
  scope :free, lambda { where('price == ?', 0) }
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :price_plan
  has_one :account
  scope :free, lambda { joins(PricePlan.free) } #<--- no!
end
```

How to define scope for users, that use service free of charge? 
This below should work, but I don't like it.

```
scope :free,-> where(priceplan_id: PricePlan.free.pluck(:id))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be

**Solution 1**: Use condition on relation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your current code
  belongs_to :free_price_plan, -> { free }, class_name: 'PricePlan'
  belongs_to :premium_price_plan, -> { premium }, class_name: 'PricePlan'
end
```

**Solution 2**: Define a scope

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your current code
  scope :free, -> {
    joins(:price_plan).merge(PricePlan.free)
  }

  scope :premium, -> {
    joins(:price_plan).merge(PricePlan.premium)
  }
end
```

Comment: Can you use naked scopes like that?

Comment: Solution 2 is the answer